# How can I fix this kindle?

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, amazon, software, hardware

I tried to turn on my kindle DX and I found it in this state:
 [image]

The screen was normal prior to that with no anomalies.The external screen is fine with no cracks or scratches.
What I remember one day before is that I dropped my keyboard on the kindle's screen; however, since the screen showed no external damage I never gave it much thought.

What has exactly happened to my Kindle? and what are my options for repair?
I'm out of the warantee.

Comment: As Ced says, it looks like your screen broke internally. The screen technology is similar in certain ways to the tech used in a basic calculator, and the same principles apply: when you break the screen, it's game over. You have no choice but to replace the screen or just replace the device.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest there are high probabilities that your screen died when you dropped the keyboard on the kindle's screen.
My suggestion if you wanna keep it would be to remplace the entire screen by [buying](https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/Genuine-ED097OC1-Screen-9-7-Inch-E-ink-Amazon-Kindle-DX-Display-Replacement/1433756276) a brand new and following a tutorial like [this one.](https://fr.ifixit.com/Tutoriel/Amazon+Kindle+DX+LCD+Replacement/73689)

Otherwise taking into account that the release date of the kindle DX was on July 1, 2010. You may consider buying a newer model from Amazon Kindle or Rakuten Kobo.